# passing variable to SQL statement within CLLE program

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm hoping to get some help with this SQL statement.

```
RUNSQL_X SQL('UPDATE mylib/myfile SET N53DSC = ''' *CAT &TEXT *CAT ''' where ''' *CAT + &N53GIDCHAR *CAT ''' = ''' *CAT &CHARID# *CAT ''')') COMMIT(*NONE)
```

When I run this inside my `CLLE` program, I get the following message:

> Token ) was not valid. Valid tokens: OR USE SKIP WAIT WITH.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First off...take care using dyamic statements like this as they can open up the possibility of SQL injection attacks.  It'd be safer to use a static SQL statement inside of RPGLE.

But if you must use CLLE... try the following:

```
dcl  &quote  type(*CHAR) len(1) value ('''')
dcl  &stmt   type(*char) len(512)

chgvar  var(&stmt) value('UPDATE mylib/myfile set n53dsc = ' + 
              *CAT &quote *CAT &TEXT *CAT &quote +
              *CAT 'where ' *CAT &N53GIDCHAR *CAT '=' +
              *CAT &quote *CAT &CHARID# *CAT &quote) 
dmpclpgm
runsql_x SQL(&stmt) COMMIT(*NONE)
```

**EDIT**
Based on your comment.  I'd liek to point out that reading one record at a time and updating (with SQL) is a poor use of SQL.

SQL is designed & optimised for set a time operations...

I think the following would accomplish what you are trying to do..(not sure exactly what fields are in which tables)

```
update mylib/myfile
   set n53dsc = <TEXT>
  where n53gidchar in (select n53gidchar from mylib/otherfile)
        and n53gidchar = charid#
```

Comment: Almost @Charles.  What the program does is open two files, read one and if the value in N53GIDCHAR is = to the value in CHARID#, then update the N53DSC field.                                               What is being returned now is this...

   2600 - RUNSQL_X SQL('UPDATE misbxg/nw0153F set n53dsc   = ''Did this change WHERE''1494''=''1494''') COMMIT(*NONE)

Token 1494 was not valid. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH WHERE.

Perhaps it's adding one too many quotes?

Comment: Try it now.  I was missing a &quote after the *CAT &TEXT.  ALso, changed it to use a &STMT variable to hold the entire SQL statement.  Lastly, added a DMPCLPGM so you'll be able to see the entire statement.  Makes it easier to figure out what's wrong.